# Unsquish Text In Notepad++ 5.9.3

Tags: notepad++

The text seems to be very squished horizontally together in my Notepad++. I have gone through the settings but cannot seem to find out how to unstretch it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a monospaced font such as Consolas, Courier New, Lucida Console or equivalent.